# problems with usb virtual com port stm32f769 discovery

Tags: usb, stm32, hal, stm32f7

I am trying to initialise VCP through usb on n stm32f769 diso.

The following function seems happy enough. But nothing happens. `ioreg -p IOUSB` doesn't detect anything

Where do I look next?

I am using vscode, platformio, stm hal, all on a mac m2 pro

```
uint8_t MX_USB_DEVICE_Init(void)
{

   /\* USER CODE BEGIN USB_DEVICE_Init_PreTreatment */
   /* USER CODE END USB_DEVICE_Init_PreTreatment */
   /* Init Device Library, add supported class and start the library. */
    if (USBD_Init(&USBD_Device, &VCP_Desc, 0) != USBD_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (USBD_RegisterClass(&USBD_Device, USBD_CDC_CLASS) != USBD_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (USBD_CDC_RegisterInterface(&USBD_Device, &USBD_CDC_fops) != USBD_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (USBD_Start(&USBD_Device) != USBD_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_DEVICE_Init_PostTreatment */
    return 1;
    /* USER CODE END USB_DEVICE_Init_PostTreatment \*/
}
```

I was expecting `ioreg -p IOUSB` to display the usb cdc device.
It only shows the st-link peripheral

Comment: The board has two USB connectors. One is for the ST-Link. That's the one you use for uploading and debugging. The other one is for the USB high-speed interface. You need to connect both USB ports to your computer. But most importantly, it looks as if your are configuring the USB full-speed peripheral, which is not connected to a USB port on this particular board.

Comment: I am using both ports, so its not that. The full-speed issue was very well spotted. I will redo, and post results. Many thanks.

Comment: Solved . Redid the config in cubemx as a HS device. VCP now online